# (TimescaleDB) - How can I optimise a JOIN query on a dataset of ~2 billion rows. (too slow right now)

Tags: postgresql, join, indexing, query-performance, timescaledb

I have a database that sources a lot of sensor data (IOT like) - and I store this data in a table called `events`. (Structure below)

Now users can also subscribe on changes of specific signals (by id) and they can request all signal events starting from a specific point (only the signals they are subscribed too).

The problem is that this query is really slow (1 minute+) and I can't understand why it is this slow. Am I missing an index of sorts?

The query I want to execute:

```
SELECT events.*
FROM Events
   JOIN subscription_signal
      ON subscription_signal.subscription_id = $1 AND
         events.signal_id = subscription_signal.signal_id
WHERE source_time > $2
ORDER BY source_time ASC
LIMIT $3
```

```
create table if not exists events
(
    source_time timestamp with time zone not null,
    added_time timestamp with time zone default now(),
    signal_id integer not null,
    data_type text,
    analog_value numeric(18,4) default 0,
    digital_value boolean default false
);

create index if not exists events_source_time_idx
    on new_events (source_time desc);

create index if not exists vents_signal_id_source_time_index
    on new_events (signal_id, source_time);

create index if not exists events_source_time_signal_id_index
    on new_events (source_time, signal_id);

create index if not exists events_signal_id_index
    on new_events (signal_id);

create table if not exists subscription_signal
(
    subscription_id integer not null,
    signal_id integer not null,
    constraint subscription_signal_subscription_id_signal_id_uindex
        unique (subscription_id, signal_id)
);
```

I already tried to add multiple indexes but nothing seems to improve the query time.

Below is an `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` using a `subscription_id` of 11 which has 114 `signal_id`s in the `subscription_signal` table.

`EXPLAIN ANALYZE`:

```
Limit  (cost=0.71..0.71 rows=500 width=33) (actual time=24018.215..372251.399 rows=274 loops=1)
  ->  Nested Loop  (cost=0.71..0.30 rows=72839547 width=33) (actual time=24018.214..372251.287 rows=274 loops=1)
        ->  Append  (cost=0.43..0.00 rows=0 width=33) (actual time=0.038..141484.028 rows=133615131 loops=1)
              ->  Index Scan Backward using _hyper_1_2_chunk_events_source_timestamp_idx on _hyper_1_2_chunk  (cost=0.43..184291.13 rows=5852043 width=32) (actual time=0.038..9359.166 rows=5852114 loops=1)
                    Index Cond: (source_timestamp > '2018-07-05 09:00:00.88+00'::timestamp with time zone)
              ->  Index Scan Backward using _hyper_1_3_chunk_events_source_timestamp_idx on _hyper_1_3_chunk  (cost=0.43..119619.56 rows=3733367 width=33) (actual time=0.096..4841.893 rows=3733367 loops=1)
                    Index Cond: (source_timestamp > '2018-07-05 09:00:00.88+00'::timestamp with time zone)
              ->  Index Scan Backward using _hyper_1_4_chunk_events_source_timestamp_idx on _hyper_1_4_chunk  (cost=0.43..101122.76 rows=3188104 width=33) (actual time=0.065..2088.177 rows=3188104 loops=1)
                    Index Cond: (source_timestamp > '2018-07-05 09:00:00.88+00'::timestamp with time zone)
              ->  Index Scan Backward using _hyper_1_5_chunk_events_source_timestamp_idx on _hyper_1_5_chunk  (cost=0.43..103410.32 rows=3223702 width=33) (actual time=0.055..3959.425 rows=3223702 loops=1)
                    Index Cond: (source_timestamp > '2018-07-05 09:00:00.88+00'::timestamp with time zone)
              ->  Index Scan Backward using _hyper_1_6_chunk_events_source_timestamp_idx on _hyper_1_6_chunk  (cost=0.43..130778.92 rows=4116765 width=33) (actual time=0.039..2917.270 rows=4116765 loops=1)
                    Index Cond: (source_timestamp > '2018-07-05 09:00:00.88+00'::timestamp with time zone)
              ->  Index Scan Backward using _hyper_1_7_chunk_events_source_timestamp_idx on _hyper_1_7_chunk  (cost=0.43..160960.05 rows=5047161 width=33) (actual time=0.030..3801.518 rows=5047161 loops=1)
                    Index Cond: (source_timestamp > '2018-07-05 09:00:00.88+00'::timestamp with time zone)
              ->  Index Scan Backward using _hyper_1_8_chunk_events_source_timestamp_idx on _hyper_1_8_chunk  (cost=0.43..161138.72 rows=5067119 width=33) (actual time=0.046..3106.090 rows=5067119 loops=1)
                    Index Cond: (source_timestamp > '2018-07-05 09:00:00.88+00'::timestamp with time zone)
              ->  Index Scan Backward using _hyper_1_9_chunk_events_source_timestamp_idx on _hyper_1_9_chunk  (cost=0.43..148498.73 rows=4523834 width=33) (actual time=0.050..4114.502 rows=4535789 loops=1)
                    Index Cond: (source_timestamp > '2018-07-05 09:00:00.88+00'::timestamp with time zone)
              ->  Index Scan Backward using _hyper_1_10_chunk_events_source_timestamp_idx on _hyper_1_10_chunk  (cost=0.43..149195.92 rows=4690233 width=33) (actual time=0.029..4904.397 rows=4690344 loops=1)
                    Index Cond: (source_timestamp > '2018-07-05 09:00:00.88+00'::timestamp with time zone)
              ->  Index Scan Backward using _hyper_1_11_chunk_events_source_timestamp_idx on _hyper_1_11_chunk  (cost=0.43..148274.33 rows=4627748 width=33) (actual time=0.034..4086.343 rows=4645264 loops=1)
                    Index Cond: (source_timestamp > '2018-07-05 09:00:00.88+00'::timestamp with time zone)
              ->  Index Scan Backward using _hyper_1_12_chunk_events_source_timestamp_idx on _hyper_1_12_chunk  (cost=0.43..147687.64 rows=4608886 width=33) (actual time=0.054..4305.309 rows=4612240 loops=1)
                    Index Cond: (source_timestamp > '2018-07-05 09:00:00.88+00'::timestamp with time zone)
              ->  Index Scan Backward using _hyper_1_13_chunk_events_source_timestamp_idx on _hyper_1_13_chunk  (cost=0.43..137341.97 rows=4280236 width=33) (actual time=0.049..6224.372 rows=4301055 loops=1)
                    Index Cond: (source_timestamp > '2018-07-05 09:00:00.88+00'::timestamp with time zone)
              ->  Index Scan Backward using _hyper_1_14_chunk_events_source_timestamp_idx on _hyper_1_14_chunk  (cost=0.43..141762.95 rows=4460189 width=33) (actual time=0.054..2724.318 rows=4460189 loops=1)
                    Index Cond: (source_timestamp > '2018-07-05 09:00:00.88+00'::timestamp with time zone)
              ->  Index Scan Backward using _hyper_1_15_chunk_events_source_timestamp_idx on _hyper_1_15_chunk  (cost=0.43..143731.09 rows=4522774 width=33) (actual time=0.029..3981.750 rows=4522875 loops=1)
                    Index Cond: (source_timestamp > '2018-07-05 09:00:00.88+00'::timestamp with time zone)
              ->  Index Scan Backward using _hyper_1_16_chunk_events_source_timestamp_idx on _hyper_1_16_chunk  (cost=0.43..150538.02 rows=4721239 width=33) (actual time=0.062..6109.135 rows=4722110 loops=1)
                    Index Cond: (source_timestamp > '2018-07-05 09:00:00.88+00'::timestamp with time zone)
              ->  Index Scan Backward using _hyper_1_17_chunk_events_source_timestamp_idx on _hyper_1_17_chunk  (cost=0.43..142216.56 rows=4475544 width=33) (actual time=0.060..3955.418 rows=4475511 loops=1)
                    Index Cond: (source_timestamp > '2018-07-05 09:00:00.88+00'::timestamp with time zone)
              ->  Index Scan Backward using _hyper_1_18_chunk_events_source_timestamp_idx on _hyper_1_18_chunk  (cost=0.43..137131.47 rows=4293396 width=33) (actual time=0.072..5002.332 rows=4294763 loops=1)
                    Index Cond: (source_timestamp > '2018-07-05 09:00:00.88+00'::timestamp with time zone)
              ->  Index Scan Backward using _hyper_1_19_chunk_events_source_timestamp_idx on _hyper_1_19_chunk  (cost=0.43..136908.18 rows=4284368 width=33) (actual time=0.100..5866.330 rows=4279079 loops=1)
                    Index Cond: (source_timestamp > '2018-07-05 09:00:00.88+00'::timestamp with time zone)
              ->  Index Scan Backward using _hyper_1_20_chunk_events_source_timestamp_idx on _hyper_1_20_chunk  (cost=0.43..142385.12 rows=4475205 width=33) (actual time=0.081..3407.288 rows=4475211 loops=1)
                    Index Cond: (source_timestamp > '2018-07-05 09:00:00.88+00'::timestamp with time zone)
              ->  Index Scan Backward using _hyper_1_21_chunk_events_source_timestamp_idx on _hyper_1_21_chunk  (cost=0.43..154334.53 rows=4854714 width=33) (actual time=0.082..3049.434 rows=4855427 loops=1)
                    Index Cond: (source_timestamp > '2018-07-05 09:00:00.88+00'::timestamp with time zone)
              ->  Index Scan Backward using _hyper_1_22_chunk_events_source_timestamp_idx on _hyper_1_22_chunk  (cost=0.43..149148.27 rows=4690356 width=33) (actual time=0.051..5394.662 rows=4690489 loops=1)
                    Index Cond: (source_timestamp > '2018-07-05 09:00:00.88+00'::timestamp with time zone)
              ->  Index Scan Backward using _hyper_1_23_chunk_events_source_timestamp_idx on _hyper_1_23_chunk  (cost=0.43..147018.61 rows=4624741 width=33) (actual time=0.042..2781.965 rows=4624838 loops=1)
                    Index Cond: (source_timestamp > '2018-07-05 09:00:00.88+00'::timestamp with time zone)
              ->  Index Scan Backward using _hyper_1_24_chunk_events_source_timestamp_idx on _hyper_1_24_chunk  (cost=0.43..151841.97 rows=4774145 width=33) (actual time=0.053..5188.953 rows=4776442 loops=1)
                    Index Cond: (source_timestamp > '2018-07-05 09:00:00.88+00'::timestamp with time zone)
              ->  Index Scan Backward using _hyper_1_25_chunk_events_source_timestamp_idx on _hyper_1_25_chunk  (cost=0.43..141470.65 rows=4449075 width=32) (actual time=0.066..4113.208 rows=4451125 loops=1)
                    Index Cond: (source_timestamp > '2018-07-05 09:00:00.88+00'::timestamp with time zone)
              ->  Index Scan Backward using _hyper_1_26_chunk_events_source_timestamp_idx on _hyper_1_26_chunk  (cost=0.43..133228.19 rows=4192152 width=32) (actual time=0.073..3794.901 rows=4192089 loops=1)
                    Index Cond: (source_timestamp > '2018-07-05 09:00:00.88+00'::timestamp with time zone)
              ->  Index Scan Backward using _hyper_1_27_chunk_events_source_timestamp_idx on _hyper_1_27_chunk  (cost=0.43..93412.39 rows=2946643 width=33) (actual time=0.034..2600.225 rows=2946741 loops=1)
                    Index Cond: (source_timestamp > '2018-07-05 09:00:00.88+00'::timestamp with time zone)
              ->  Index Scan Backward using _hyper_1_28_chunk_events_source_timestamp_idx on _hyper_1_28_chunk  (cost=0.43..107666.24 rows=3380023 width=33) (actual time=0.061..4010.668 rows=3380023 loops=1)
                    Index Cond: (source_timestamp > '2018-07-05 09:00:00.88+00'::timestamp with time zone)
              ->  Index Scan Backward using _hyper_1_29_chunk_events_source_timestamp_idx on _hyper_1_29_chunk  (cost=0.43..139070.65 rows=4376229 width=33) (actual time=0.058..3597.805 rows=4376329 loops=1)
                    Index Cond: (source_timestamp > '2018-07-05 09:00:00.88+00'::timestamp with time zone)
              ->  Index Scan Backward using _hyper_1_30_chunk_events_source_timestamp_idx on _hyper_1_30_chunk  (cost=0.43..133595.88 rows=4204134 width=33) (actual time=0.047..3998.751 rows=4204442 loops=1)
                    Index Cond: (source_timestamp > '2018-07-05 09:00:00.88+00'::timestamp with time zone)
              ->  Index Scan Backward using _hyper_1_31_chunk_events_source_timestamp_idx on _hyper_1_31_chunk  (cost=0.43..139554.54 rows=4391212 width=33) (actual time=0.054..4415.468 rows=4391126 loops=1)
                    Index Cond: (source_timestamp > '2018-07-05 09:00:00.88+00'::timestamp with time zone)
              ->  Index Scan Backward using _hyper_1_32_chunk_events_source_timestamp_idx on _hyper_1_32_chunk  (cost=0.43..78562.22 rows=2463045 width=33) (actual time=0.054..1672.220 rows=2482753 loops=1)
                    Index Cond: (source_timestamp > '2018-07-05 09:00:00.88+00'::timestamp with time zone)
              ->  Index Scan Backward using _hyper_1_1_chunk_events_source_timestamp_idx on _hyper_1_1_chunk  (cost=0.14..5.59 rows=62 width=32) (actual time=12.567..12.603 rows=62 loops=1)
                    Index Cond: (source_timestamp > '2018-07-05 09:00:00.88+00'::timestamp with time zone)
              ->  Index Scan Backward using _hyper_1_65_chunk_events_source_timestamp_idx on _hyper_1_65_chunk  (cost=0.15..16.92 rows=267 width=73) (actual time=8.766..8.768 rows=1 loops=1)
                    Index Cond: (source_timestamp > '2018-07-05 09:00:00.88+00'::timestamp with time zone)
              ->  Index Scan Backward using _hyper_1_88_chunk_events_source_timestamp_idx on _hyper_1_88_chunk  (cost=0.15..12.90 rows=364 width=32) (actual time=7.869..8.008 rows=374 loops=1)
                    Index Cond: (source_timestamp > '2018-07-05 09:00:00.88+00'::timestamp with time zone)
              ->  Index Scan Backward using _hyper_1_89_chunk_events_source_timestamp_idx on _hyper_1_89_chunk  (cost=0.14..6.16 rows=94 width=32) (actual time=0.017..0.047 rows=108 loops=1)
                    Index Cond: (source_timestamp > '2018-07-05 09:00:00.88+00'::timestamp with time zone)
        ->  Index Only Scan using subscription_signal_subscription_id_signal_id_uindex on subscription_signal  (cost=0.28..0.30 rows=1 width=4) (actual time=0.001..0.001 rows=0 loops=133615131)
              Index Cond: ((subscription_id = 11) AND (signal_id = _hyper_1_2_chunk.signal_id))
              Heap Fetches: 274
Planning time: 8.924 ms
Execution time: 372252.454 ms
```

`EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS)`:

```
Limit  (cost=0.71..0.71 rows=500 width=33) (actual time=19504.097..315933.258 rows=274 loops=1)
  Buffers: shared hit=269362667 read=1352546
  ->  Nested Loop  (cost=0.71..0.30 rows=72839557 width=33) (actual time=19504.096..315933.158 rows=274 loops=1)
        Buffers: shared hit=269362667 read=1352546
        ->  Append  (cost=0.43..0.00 rows=0 width=33) (actual time=14.950..96402.213 rows=133615135 loops=1)
              Buffers: shared hit=2132123 read=1352546
              ->  Index Scan Backward using _hyper_1_2_chunk_events_source_timestamp_idx on _hyper_1_2_chunk  (cost=0.43..184291.13 rows=5852043 width=32) (actual time=0.019..4707.774 rows=5852114 loops=1)
                    Index Cond: (source_timestamp > '2018-07-05 09:00:00.88+00'::timestamp with time zone)
                    Buffers: shared hit=265328 read=20465
              ->  Index Scan Backward using _hyper_1_3_chunk_events_source_timestamp_idx on _hyper_1_3_chunk  (cost=0.43..119619.56 rows=3733367 width=33) (actual time=0.057..2192.118 rows=3733367 loops=1)
                    Index Cond: (source_timestamp > '2018-07-05 09:00:00.88+00'::timestamp with time zone)
                    Buffers: shared hit=72014 read=25960
              ->  Index Scan Backward using _hyper_1_4_chunk_events_source_timestamp_idx on _hyper_1_4_chunk  (cost=0.43..101122.76 rows=3188104 width=33) (actual time=0.064..1964.159 rows=3188104 loops=1)
                    Index Cond: (source_timestamp > '2018-07-05 09:00:00.88+00'::timestamp with time zone)
                    Buffers: shared hit=60389 read=23035
              ->  Index Scan Backward using _hyper_1_5_chunk_events_source_timestamp_idx on _hyper_1_5_chunk  (cost=0.43..103410.32 rows=3223702 width=33) (actual time=0.033..1769.853 rows=3223702 loops=1)
                    Index Cond: (source_timestamp > '2018-07-05 09:00:00.88+00'::timestamp with time zone)
                    Buffers: shared hit=61428 read=23456
              ->  Index Scan Backward using _hyper_1_6_chunk_events_source_timestamp_idx on _hyper_1_6_chunk  (cost=0.43..130778.92 rows=4116765 width=33) (actual time=0.029..2138.480 rows=4116765 loops=1)
                    Index Cond: (source_timestamp > '2018-07-05 09:00:00.88+00'::timestamp with time zone)
                    Buffers: shared hit=72968 read=30233
              ->  Index Scan Backward using _hyper_1_7_chunk_events_source_timestamp_idx on _hyper_1_7_chunk  (cost=0.43..160960.05 rows=5047161 width=33) (actual time=0.029..2628.668 rows=5047161 loops=1)
                    Index Cond: (source_timestamp > '2018-07-05 09:00:00.88+00'::timestamp with time zone)
                    Buffers: shared hit=93741 read=35257
              ->  Index Scan Backward using _hyper_1_8_chunk_events_source_timestamp_idx on _hyper_1_8_chunk  (cost=0.43..161138.72 rows=5067119 width=33) (actual time=0.036..2523.536 rows=5067119 loops=1)
                    Index Cond: (source_timestamp > '2018-07-05 09:00:00.88+00'::timestamp with time zone)
                    Buffers: shared hit=93406 read=35384
              ->  Index Scan Backward using _hyper_1_9_chunk_events_source_timestamp_idx on _hyper_1_9_chunk  (cost=0.43..148498.73 rows=4523834 width=33) (actual time=0.024..2890.820 rows=4535789 loops=1)
                    Index Cond: (source_timestamp > '2018-07-05 09:00:00.88+00'::timestamp with time zone)
                    Buffers: shared hit=86274 read=32252
              ->  Index Scan Backward using _hyper_1_10_chunk_events_source_timestamp_idx on _hyper_1_10_chunk  (cost=0.43..149195.92 rows=4690233 width=33) (actual time=0.025..2765.170 rows=4690344 loops=1)
                    Index Cond: (source_timestamp > '2018-07-05 09:00:00.88+00'::timestamp with time zone)
                    Buffers: shared hit=84883 read=37839
              ->  Index Scan Backward using _hyper_1_11_chunk_events_source_timestamp_idx on _hyper_1_11_chunk  (cost=0.43..148274.33 rows=4627748 width=33) (actual time=0.027..2902.346 rows=4645264 loops=1)
                    Index Cond: (source_timestamp > '2018-07-05 09:00:00.88+00'::timestamp with time zone)
                    Buffers: shared hit=64046 read=59908
              ->  Index Scan Backward using _hyper_1_12_chunk_events_source_timestamp_idx on _hyper_1_12_chunk  (cost=0.43..147687.64 rows=4608886 width=33) (actual time=0.049..3556.359 rows=4612240 loops=1)
                    Index Cond: (source_timestamp > '2018-07-05 09:00:00.88+00'::timestamp with time zone)
                    Buffers: shared hit=63025 read=59693
              ->  Index Scan Backward using _hyper_1_13_chunk_events_source_timestamp_idx on _hyper_1_13_chunk  (cost=0.43..137341.97 rows=4280236 width=33) (actual time=0.027..3361.873 rows=4301055 loops=1)
                    Index Cond: (source_timestamp > '2018-07-05 09:00:00.88+00'::timestamp with time zone)
                    Buffers: shared hit=54986 read=55571
              ->  Index Scan Backward using _hyper_1_14_chunk_events_source_timestamp_idx on _hyper_1_14_chunk  (cost=0.43..141762.95 rows=4460189 width=33) (actual time=0.028..2859.309 rows=4460189 loops=1)
                    Index Cond: (source_timestamp > '2018-07-05 09:00:00.88+00'::timestamp with time zone)
                    Buffers: shared hit=50767 read=57846
              ->  Index Scan Backward using _hyper_1_15_chunk_events_source_timestamp_idx on _hyper_1_15_chunk  (cost=0.43..143731.09 rows=4522774 width=33) (actual time=0.028..3143.475 rows=4522875 loops=1)
                    Index Cond: (source_timestamp > '2018-07-05 09:00:00.88+00'::timestamp with time zone)
                    Buffers: shared hit=54841 read=58390
              ->  Index Scan Backward using _hyper_1_16_chunk_events_source_timestamp_idx on _hyper_1_16_chunk  (cost=0.43..150538.02 rows=4721239 width=33) (actual time=0.028..2854.384 rows=4722110 loops=1)
                    Index Cond: (source_timestamp > '2018-07-05 09:00:00.88+00'::timestamp with time zone)
                    Buffers: shared hit=56488 read=61480
              ->  Index Scan Backward using _hyper_1_17_chunk_events_source_timestamp_idx on _hyper_1_17_chunk  (cost=0.43..142216.56 rows=4475544 width=33) (actual time=0.060..2522.463 rows=4475511 loops=1)
                    Index Cond: (source_timestamp > '2018-07-05 09:00:00.88+00'::timestamp with time zone)
                    Buffers: shared hit=54403 read=57798
              ->  Index Scan Backward using _hyper_1_18_chunk_events_source_timestamp_idx on _hyper_1_18_chunk  (cost=0.43..137131.47 rows=4293396 width=33) (actual time=0.051..2854.544 rows=4294763 loops=1)
                    Index Cond: (source_timestamp > '2018-07-05 09:00:00.88+00'::timestamp with time zone)
                    Buffers: shared hit=49427 read=56050
              ->  Index Scan Backward using _hyper_1_19_chunk_events_source_timestamp_idx on _hyper_1_19_chunk  (cost=0.43..136908.18 rows=4284368 width=33) (actual time=0.033..2673.792 rows=4279079 loops=1)
                    Index Cond: (source_timestamp > '2018-07-05 09:00:00.88+00'::timestamp with time zone)
                    Buffers: shared hit=49055 read=55966
              ->  Index Scan Backward using _hyper_1_20_chunk_events_source_timestamp_idx on _hyper_1_20_chunk  (cost=0.43..142385.12 rows=4475205 width=33) (actual time=0.029..2793.156 rows=4475211 loops=1)
                    Index Cond: (source_timestamp > '2018-07-05 09:00:00.88+00'::timestamp with time zone)
                    Buffers: shared hit=60428 read=57064
              ->  Index Scan Backward using _hyper_1_21_chunk_events_source_timestamp_idx on _hyper_1_21_chunk  (cost=0.43..154334.53 rows=4854714 width=33) (actual time=0.022..2701.886 rows=4855427 loops=1)
                    Index Cond: (source_timestamp > '2018-07-05 09:00:00.88+00'::timestamp with time zone)
                    Buffers: shared hit=63812 read=62451
              ->  Index Scan Backward using _hyper_1_22_chunk_events_source_timestamp_idx on _hyper_1_22_chunk  (cost=0.43..149148.27 rows=4690356 width=33) (actual time=0.028..2763.383 rows=4690489 loops=1)
                    Index Cond: (source_timestamp > '2018-07-05 09:00:00.88+00'::timestamp with time zone)
                    Buffers: shared hit=62684 read=60247
              ->  Index Scan Backward using _hyper_1_23_chunk_events_source_timestamp_idx on _hyper_1_23_chunk  (cost=0.43..147018.61 rows=4624741 width=33) (actual time=0.025..2823.549 rows=4624838 loops=1)
                    Index Cond: (source_timestamp > '2018-07-05 09:00:00.88+00'::timestamp with time zone)
                    Buffers: shared hit=52489 read=59932
              ->  Index Scan Backward using _hyper_1_24_chunk_events_source_timestamp_idx on _hyper_1_24_chunk  (cost=0.43..151841.97 rows=4774145 width=33) (actual time=0.060..2819.668 rows=4776442 loops=1)
                    Index Cond: (source_timestamp > '2018-07-05 09:00:00.88+00'::timestamp with time zone)
                    Buffers: shared hit=48917 read=62622
              ->  Index Scan Backward using _hyper_1_25_chunk_events_source_timestamp_idx on _hyper_1_25_chunk  (cost=0.43..141470.65 rows=4449075 width=32) (actual time=0.057..2554.301 rows=4451125 loops=1)
                    Index Cond: (source_timestamp > '2018-07-05 09:00:00.88+00'::timestamp with time zone)
                    Buffers: shared hit=40129 read=58563
              ->  Index Scan Backward using _hyper_1_26_chunk_events_source_timestamp_idx on _hyper_1_26_chunk  (cost=0.43..133228.19 rows=4192152 width=32) (actual time=0.049..2467.922 rows=4192089 loops=1)
                    Index Cond: (source_timestamp > '2018-07-05 09:00:00.88+00'::timestamp with time zone)
                    Buffers: shared hit=55849 read=37756
              ->  Index Scan Backward using _hyper_1_27_chunk_events_source_timestamp_idx on _hyper_1_27_chunk  (cost=0.43..93412.39 rows=2946643 width=33) (actual time=0.048..1754.935 rows=2946741 loops=1)
                    Index Cond: (source_timestamp > '2018-07-05 09:00:00.88+00'::timestamp with time zone)
                    Buffers: shared hit=47717 read=23505
              ->  Index Scan Backward using _hyper_1_28_chunk_events_source_timestamp_idx on _hyper_1_28_chunk  (cost=0.43..107666.24 rows=3380023 width=33) (actual time=0.027..1896.157 rows=3380023 loops=1)
                    Index Cond: (source_timestamp > '2018-07-05 09:00:00.88+00'::timestamp with time zone)
                    Buffers: shared hit=66850 read=23284
              ->  Index Scan Backward using _hyper_1_29_chunk_events_source_timestamp_idx on _hyper_1_29_chunk  (cost=0.43..139070.65 rows=4376229 width=33) (actual time=0.028..2469.809 rows=4376329 loops=1)
                    Index Cond: (source_timestamp > '2018-07-05 09:00:00.88+00'::timestamp with time zone)
                    Buffers: shared hit=77118 read=31953
              ->  Index Scan Backward using _hyper_1_30_chunk_events_source_timestamp_idx on _hyper_1_30_chunk  (cost=0.43..133595.88 rows=4204134 width=33) (actual time=0.032..2862.879 rows=4204442 loops=1)
                    Index Cond: (source_timestamp > '2018-07-05 09:00:00.88+00'::timestamp with time zone)
                    Buffers: shared hit=64898 read=33521
              ->  Index Scan Backward using _hyper_1_31_chunk_events_source_timestamp_idx on _hyper_1_31_chunk  (cost=0.43..139554.54 rows=4391212 width=33) (actual time=0.038..2431.625 rows=4391126 loops=1)
                    Index Cond: (source_timestamp > '2018-07-05 09:00:00.88+00'::timestamp with time zone)
                    Buffers: shared hit=68406 read=34357
              ->  Index Scan Backward using _hyper_1_32_chunk_events_source_timestamp_idx on _hyper_1_32_chunk  (cost=0.43..78562.22 rows=2463045 width=33) (actual time=0.060..1396.815 rows=2482753 loops=1)
                    Index Cond: (source_timestamp > '2018-07-05 09:00:00.88+00'::timestamp with time zone)
                    Buffers: shared hit=35270 read=20706
              ->  Index Scan Backward using _hyper_1_1_chunk_events_source_timestamp_idx on _hyper_1_1_chunk  (cost=0.14..5.59 rows=62 width=32) (actual time=0.030..0.095 rows=62 loops=1)
                    Index Cond: (source_timestamp > '2018-07-05 09:00:00.88+00'::timestamp with time zone)
                    Buffers: shared hit=4 read=1
              ->  Index Scan Backward using _hyper_1_65_chunk_events_source_timestamp_idx on _hyper_1_65_chunk  (cost=0.15..16.92 rows=267 width=73) (actual time=0.042..0.043 rows=1 loops=1)
                    Index Cond: (source_timestamp > '2018-07-05 09:00:00.88+00'::timestamp with time zone)
                    Buffers: shared hit=2 read=1
              ->  Index Scan Backward using _hyper_1_88_chunk_events_source_timestamp_idx on _hyper_1_88_chunk  (cost=0.15..12.90 rows=364 width=32) (actual time=0.022..0.140 rows=374 loops=1)
                    Index Cond: (source_timestamp > '2018-07-05 09:00:00.88+00'::timestamp with time zone)
                    Buffers: shared hit=72
              ->  Index Scan Backward using _hyper_1_89_chunk_events_source_timestamp_idx on _hyper_1_89_chunk  (cost=0.14..6.48 rows=112 width=32) (actual time=0.019..0.053 rows=112 loops=1)
                    Index Cond: (source_timestamp > '2018-07-05 09:00:00.88+00'::timestamp with time zone)
                    Buffers: shared hit=9
        ->  Index Only Scan using subscription_signal_subscription_id_signal_id_uindex on subscription_signal  (cost=0.28..0.30 rows=1 width=4) (actual time=0.001..0.001 rows=0 loops=133615135)
              Index Cond: ((subscription_id = 11) AND (signal_id = _hyper_1_2_chunk.signal_id))
              Heap Fetches: 274
              Buffers: shared hit=267230544
Planning time: 144.220 ms
Execution time: 315933.896 ms
```

Comment: Please show `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS)` output for the query.

Comment: Hello Laurenz, thanks for answering. I updated my question in include the analyze, will also run with buffers

Comment: `source_time desc` Why `DESC`?

Comment: From what i recall, that was the default index that timescaledb created. I might be wrong tho. Would changing that to ASC make a huge difference you think?

Comment: If `ASC` the "Scan Backward" would be forwad scan, i think...

Comment: What version of TimescaleDB are you using?

Answer (score 1):

`events` is not partitioned by `source_timestamp`, right?

PostgreSQL has no choice but to find all rows with `source_timestamp > '2018-07-05 09:00:00.88+00'`, then join the result with `events`. That can never be fast.

If omitting the `LIMIT` makes the query faster, you may gain something by nudging PostgreSQL towards *not* using a nested loop join, but given the number of rows involved, that doesn't seem likely.

If the table were partitioned by `source_timestamp`, the query would probably be much faster.

Answer (score 0):

Try removing all the indexes except of the index on `(signal_id, source_time)` and use the following query:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM events
WHERE signal_id IN (
    SELECT signal_id
    FROM subscription_signal
    WHERE subscription_id = $1)
AND source_time > $2
ORDER BY source_time
LIMIT $3
```

Then postgresql should use the remaining index for quick lookup of rows for the given `signal_id` list and then use the second part of the index in order to find rows with `source_time > $2`.

The query may work slowly in the following cases:

- if the number of matching rows is too high (for instance, exceeds ~10% of the total number of rows in the table). In this case postgresql may choose full table scan instead of index lookup.
- if the number of matching rows is moderate (<1M), but these rows are physically scattered across table storage on slow disk (HDD, network-attached persistent storage in Amazon, Google Cloud or Microsoft Azure). In this case the performance would be limited by disk `iops` and read bandwidth.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you have already solved your issue but as I came across this, you might want to review the explain output yourself: https://explain.depesz.com/s/4GYT

I don't know exactly why (yet), but the query planner should have generated a `MergeAppend` instead of an `Append` execution node to enable pushing down the `LIMIT` into each partition (index) scan as in my test setup: https://explain.depesz.com/s/Fi9C

For comparison, the same query without the limit to show the amount of test data I used here: https://explain.depesz.com/s/AJ6 *(yes, only 37M intermediate rows, but it shows the effect)*

For the impatient in numbers:

```
          Without LIMIT: 49,174.946 milliseconds
LIMIT 274 OFFSET 100000: 35,022.269 milliseconds
              LIMIT 274:      2.710 milliseconds
```

*(also different values for `LIMIT` as well as query parameters instead of constants do not result into any different plans)*

This optimization for `MergeAppend` has been in PostgreSQL since release 9.1 (see commit [6fbc323](https://github.com/postgres/postgres/commit/6fbc323c8042303a737028f9da7616896bccc517#diff-db5852f65dc1b9e17d2eb5c27ee8a1d4)) with or without Timescale using partitions but not existing for the simple `Append`, which tells me that this is the key bottleneck here. This in turn might be influenced by not up-to-date statistics (you did `analyze` on both tables, or?).

Upcoming version PostgreSQL 12 *should* also push down the `LIMIT ... OFFSET ...` into `Append` execution nodes with commit [959d00e](https://github.com/postgres/postgres/commit/959d00e9dbe4cfcf4a63bb655ac2c29a5e579246#diff-9eec96efb241db53d3929c57b9c93c3f).

OTOH, even at a Timescale-optimized table with 2+ billion rows where each partition has 10+ million rows the time can also be spent in huge parts on I/O. To test that, do execute the following and re-create an `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS, COSTS OFF)` plan:

```sql
SET track_io_timing TO ON;
```

Which then includes the times (sum) for I/O operations at each relevant node in the execution plan, e.g.:

```
 Limit (actual time=1546.517..1546.572 rows=274 loops=1)
   Buffers: shared hit=73438 read=23452
   I/O Timings: read=1316.373
   ->  Sort (actual time=1546.512..1546.536 rows=274 loops=1)
         Sort Key: e.source_time
         Sort Method: top-N heapsort  Memory: 46kB
         Buffers: shared hit=73438 read=23452
         I/O Timings: read=1316.373
         ->  Nested Loop (actual time=7.147..1524.251 rows=69293 loops=1)
               Buffers: shared hit=73438 read=23452
               I/O Timings: read=1316.373
               ->  Index Only Scan using subscription_signal_subscription_id_signal_id_uindex on subscription_signal (actual time=0.038..0.236 rows=114 loops=1)
                     Index Cond: (subscription_id = $1)
                     Heap Fetches: 114
                     Buffers: shared hit=4
               ->  Append (actual time=0.334..13.184 rows=608 loops=114)
                     Buffers: shared hit=73434 read=23452
                     I/O Timings: read=1316.373
                     ->  Seq Scan on events e (actual time=0.000..0.000 rows=0 loops=114)
                           Filter: ((source_time > $2) AND (subscription_signal.signal_id = signal_id))
                     ->  Index Scan using _hyper_5_13094_chunk_events_signal_id_source_time_index on _hyper_5_13094_chunk e_1 (actual time=0.014..0.014 rows=0 loops=114)
                           Index Cond: ((signal_id = subscription_signal.signal_id) AND (source_time > $2))
                           Buffers: shared hit=340 read=3
                           I/O Timings: read=0.851
                     ->  Index Scan using _hyper_5_13095_chunk_events_signal_id_source_time_index on _hyper_5_13095_chunk e_2 (actual time=0.009..0.009 rows=0 loops=114)
                           Index Cond: ((signal_id = subscription_signal.signal_id) AND (source_time > $2))
                           Buffers: shared hit=335 read=7
                           I/O Timings: read=0.398
...
```

This can be very helpful in order to detect whether the query actually is CPU-bound or I/O-bound (which one is the bigger bottleneck and hence, the best investment for improving the situation).

**Reduce intermediate result rows**:

Alternatively, the most important part would be to get the number of intermediate rows down dramatically. As we can see that the number of rows you actually return is ~0.000205 % of the rows matching the criteria, I really urge you to rethink your criteria.

In a time-series query you almost never ever filter with only the lower-bound, instead, come up with a reasonable interval that results in enough rows to return by the `LIMIT` in 95% of all cases and for the other 5% where there are not enough rows, simply query again with the follow-up time range.

So, just try the following query instead:

```sql
SELECT events.*
FROM Events
   JOIN subscription_signal
      ON subscription_signal.subscription_id = $1 AND
         events.signal_id = subscription_signal.signal_id
WHERE source_time > $2 AND source_time <= ($2 + '1 week'::interval)
ORDER BY source_time ASC
LIMIT $3
```

That alone should reduce the query time a lot.

Answer (score -1):

Try something like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM events
WHERE signal_id IN ( SELECT signal_id
                     FROM subscription_signal
                    WHERE subscription_id = $1
                      AND source_time > $2 )
ORDER BY source_time ASC
LIMIT $3
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply - This query also seems to be running over 5 minutes now. If i put one signal id in the IN array it's super fast (˜100ms) - but when i add around 100 it becomes really slow.

Comment: Yes, I don't see how this query should make it faster.